# Using sprintf to format printing of char array

Tags: c, printing

I have a char array that contains some string
for example

```
char* arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKL ZMN OPQOSJFS"
```

and the string

```
char* string = "ZMN"
```

Is there any printing method that will print the content of arr only after the first occurrence of string in it?
In this case it will print `" OPQOSJFS"`

What about `sprintf`, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

`sprintf` won't help you here; use `strstr` to find the occurence and then print the source string from there on:

```
// note: your string constants should be of type 'const char*'
const char* haystack = "ABCDEFGHIJKL ZMN OPQOSJFS";
const char* needle = "ZMN";

// find occurence of the string
const char* out = strstr(haystack, needle);
if(out != NULL) {
    // print string, starting from the end of the occurence
    out += strlen(needle);
    printf("The string is: %s", out);
}
```

Comment: Why do you drop `const` for `out`? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, let me tell you,

> I have a char array that contains some string for example
>
> ```
> char* arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKL ZMN OPQOSJFS"
> ```

is wrong. `"ABCDEFGHIJKL ZMN OPQOSJFS"` is a string literal, and `arr` is just a pointer, not an array.

If you *indeed* need `arr` to be called an *array*, you need to write it like

```
 char arr[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKL ZMN OPQOSJFS";
```

---

Now, for your requirement, you can have a look at [`strstr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) function, prototyped in `string.h` header.

Prototype:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

Description:

> The `strstr()` function finds the first occurrence of the substring `needle` in the string `haystack`.

So, if it returns a non-NULL pointer, you can use that value to point out the location of the substring, and using index, you can get the required part of the source string.

Answer (score 2):

`strstr` will give you a pointer on the substring you are looking for.
You can then jump after this string and `printf` its content.

```
char * sub = strstr(arr, string);
sub += strlen(string);
printf("%s\n", sub);
```